# Trying to send passwrod via expect script in sshfs

Tags: ssh, ftp, expect, sshfs

I have server that has 2fa and does not allow login using ssh keys. I want to connect via `FTP`, I am using `sshfs`.
Normal `sshfs user@host:/remote/ /local/` works fine. But I wanted to pass the passwrod using `expect` (`-o password_stdin` does not work for me).

I have defined the function in `.bashrc`

```
function mount_sshfs_with_2fa() {

  # Get the FTP password from the encrypted file
  local password=$(gpg --decrypt encrypted_password.txt)

  # Prompt for verification code
  read -p "Verification code: " otp
  echo $otp

  expect << EOF
    spawn sshfs user@host:/remote/ /local/
    expect -re "code:"
    send -- "$otp\r"
    send_user "Verification code: $otp\n"
    expect -re "Password:"
    send -- "$password\r"
    send_user "Password: $password\n"

EOF
}
```

It does not give any error but does not mount either. Please tell me what's wrong.

**debug**

`expect -d` gives

```
Verification code: 325776
325776
expect version 5.45.4
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  
set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file
spawn sshfs user@host:/remote/ /local/
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {153497}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "code:"? no
Verification code: 
expect: does "\rVerification code: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "code:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "code:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\rVerification code:"
send: sending "325776\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword:"? no


expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword:"? no
Password: 
expect: does " \r\n\rPassword: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "assword:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "assword:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\n\rPassword:"
send: sending "(my password)\r" to { exp4 }
```

**update 2**
Instead of here-code the following also does not work

```
expect -c "
    spawn sshfs user@host:/remote/ /local/
    expect "code:"
    send -- "$otp\r"
    expect "assword:"
    send -- "$password\r"
    interact
  "
```

Is `expect` something serious or just time waste? I have seen multiple solutions that worked for others gave me error! For example, `interact` does not work inside `expect` here-code?

Comment: I'm surprised that the OTP is requested before the password. However, get expect to show you what it's doing: `expect -d << EOF`

Comment: You might as well not use `-p` to read the OTP if you're going to print it next step.

Comment: no I was making sure it read it correctly.

Comment: I thought this should a standard use of except. What to do then?

Comment: Expect and the like all deal with ttys and the tty world is quite messy. It's not easy to write correct Expect script for new users.

Comment: The most common mistake may be forget to call "expect eof" at the end of the script. :)

Comment: Try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/). It's default behaviors are more user friendly (e.g. forgetting eof is ok for most of the time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's killed by `SIGHUP`. Try like this:

```
expect << EOF
    spawn -ignore SIGHUP sshfs user@host:/remote/ /local/

    set timeout -1

    expect -re "code:"
    send -- "$otp\r"
    expect -re "Password:"
    send -- "$password\r"

    expect eof
    sleep 1
EOF
```

Comment: I don't know how but it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: technically speaking sshfs (if well implemented) should be immune to SIGHUP (coming from the tty) after it goes running in background. but who knows. :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note: when the heredoc ends (at EOF), then the expect process exits, and the sshfs process will be killed.

You need to keep expect running, and you probably want to launch it in the background:

```bash
function mount_sshfs_with_2fa() {

  # Get the FTP password from the encrypted file
  local password=$(gpg --decrypt encrypted_password.txt)

  # Prompt for verification code
  read -p "Verification code: " otp

  {
    expect << EOF
      spawn sshfs user@host:/remote/ /local/
      expect -re {Verification code: $}
      send -- "$otp\r"
      expect -re {Password: $}
      send -- "$password\r"
      set timeout -1
      expect eof
EOF
  } &
}
```

Comment: I am bit confused here, I expect that `sshfs` keeps running in the background even after expect stops!

Comment: Also what if it was just ssh?

Comment: What happens when you run sshfs at the command line? You enter your OTP and password, and then what?

Comment: It works. After `sshfs user@host:/remote/ /local/ ` (and giving otp and password) it mounts and returns to $.

Comment: btw, the above solution does not work. I never thought passing password could be so difficult!